# mime-types issue with ironworker upload

Tags: ironworker, iron

I am trying to upload a worker and remotely build it in my .worker file. I get this error message.

> You have already activated mime-types 2.0, but your Gemfile requires
>   mime-types 1.25. Using bundle exec may solve this.

I have tried uninstalling mime-types and installing mime-types 1.25, but that didn't seem to fix it either.

Comment: getting same error.  any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh add this to .worker file:

```
@use_local_iron_worker_ng = true
```

from:

https://github.com/iron-io/iron_worker_ruby_ng/issues/159